# Cross join 2 table with json data and get all rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm tryng to use a join function in my SQL request.

I have two table :

**tbl_jsontesting**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | data                                                                                                                                                                               | description |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | {"complexProperties":[{"properties":{"key":"Registred","Value":"123456789"}},{"properties":{"key":"Urgency","Value":"Total"}},{"properties":{"key":"ImpactScope","Value":"All"}}]} | Some Text   |
| 2  | {"complexProperties":[{"properties":{"key":"Registred","Value":"123456788"}},{"properties":{"key":"Urgency","Value":"Total"}},{"properties":{"key":"ImpactScope","Value":"All"}}]} | Some Text2  |
| 3  | {"complexProperties":[{"properties":{"key":"Urgency","Value":"Total"}},{"properties":{"key":"ImpactScope","Value":"All"}}]}                                                        | Some Text3  |
| 4  | {}                                                                                                                                                                                 | Some Text4  |
| 5  | {"complexProperties":[]}                                                                                                                                                           | Some Text5  |
| 6  |                                                                                                                                                                                    | Some Text6  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**tbl_registred**

```
----------------------
| id        | name   |
----------------------
| 123456789 | Source |
| 123456788 | Cars   |
----------------------
```

My current query :

```sql
WITH all_line as (
    select jt.id, rg.id as id_registred, rg.name, jt.description
    from tbl_jsontesting jt
    cross join jsonb_array_elements(jt.data::jsonb -> 'complexProperties') as p(props)
    LEFT join tbl_registred rg 
        on rg.id::text = (p.props -> 'properties' ->> 'Value')
        and p.props -> 'properties' ->> 'key' = 'Registred'
),line_registred as (
    SELECT *
    FROM all_line
    WHERE id_registred IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT * FROM line_registred
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct * --distinct because of line generate by sub properties in json
FROM all_line
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM line_registred)
```

Result :

```
--------------------------------------------
| id | id_registred | name   | description |
--------------------------------------------
| 3  | null         | null   | Some Text3  |
| 2  | 123456788    | Cars   | Some Text2  |
| 1  | 123456789    | Source | Some Text   |
--------------------------------------------
```

Expected result :

```
--------------------------------------------
| id | id_registred | name   | description |
--------------------------------------------
| 6  | null         | null   | Some Text6  |
| 5  | null         | null   | Some Text5  |
| 4  | null         | null   | Some Text4  |
| 3  | null         | null   | Some Text3  |
| 2  | 123456788    | Cars   | Some Text2  |
| 1  | 123456789    | Source | Some Text   |
--------------------------------------------
```

Fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Jvq4SXUpBvJsY7H3G13xm/7

Comment: According to fiddle, "Query Error: error: invalid input syntax for type json"

Comment: Yes, it's beacause of the last row of the table tbl_jsontesting, data column is empty. If commented out : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Jvq4SXUpBvJsY7H3G13xm/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a left join to your function call.  Since a left join requires an ON condition, you can just use `ON true`.  That is a bit weird, but a commonly needed trick with lateral joins.

```
LEFT join jsonb_array_elements(nullif(jt.data,'')::jsonb -> 'complexProperties') as p(props) ON true
```

See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/76ew1fK9D5V3vopbGUuYxh/1

Comment: I don't see where I need to place or replace in my SQL request, possible to have a fiddle or full request ?

Comment: added a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks ! but it output only 3 rows. The same result as my original request. https://i.imgur.com/jg8vahP.png . I think you mistaken the link because there is no such `left join`

Comment: Sorry I guess didn't save my changes.  New link should be fixed now.

Comment: Perfect, it's working ! Thanks for the tips for `ON true` on join